# How to serialize a data entity or a class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization

I want to save `sessionState` into a custom sql database but it needs the data to be serialized and gives me this error.

> Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and
>   'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects,
>   and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are
>   not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization
>   is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.

Here is my class:

```
 [Serializable()]
    public class Cart
    {
        private List<CartLine> lineCollection = new List<CartLine>();
        public void AddItem(Product product, int quantity)
        {
            CartLine line = lineCollection
                .Where(p => p.Product.ProductID == product.ProductID)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            if (line == null)
            {
                lineCollection.Add(new CartLine { Product = product, Quantity = quantity });
            }
            else
            {
                line.Quantity += quantity;
            }
        }
        public void RemoveLine(Product product)
        {
            lineCollection.RemoveAll(l => l.Product.ProductID == product.ProductID);
        }
        public decimal ComputeTotalValue()
        {
            return lineCollection.Sum(e => e.Product.ProductPrice * e.Quantity);
        }
        public void Clear()
        {
            lineCollection.Clear();
        }
        public IEnumerable<CartLine> Lines
        {
            get { return lineCollection; }
        }
        [Serializable()]
        public class CartLine
        {
            public Product Product { get; set; }
            public int Quantity { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

And here is how I get and set session data via an Interface IModelBinder.
[Serializable()]

```
 public class CartModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        private const string sessionKey = "Cart";

        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            Cart cart = null;
            if (controllerContext.HttpContext.Session != null)
            {
                cart = (Cart)controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[sessionKey];
            }
            if (cart == null)
            {
                cart = new Cart();
                if (controllerContext.HttpContext.Session != null)
                    controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[sessionKey] = cart;
            }
            return cart;
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: How is this question related, even remotely, to sql server?

Comment: nope its on a local development machine @ZoharPeled